# A strange behavior about the Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I been use Promise in some project for some time.
Most of its syntax can easy to understand, but today i find a strange  behavior about it.

As I know, Promise can also handle the `then` method return, if its 'thenable' too.

I'm very confused about the following two situation, Why the second show such behavior...

```
// right
// show the message exact like expect
'use strict';
const startPrompt = () => {

    const questionPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('first 2');resolve();
        }, 2000);
    }).then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('second 2');resolve();
            }, 2000);
        })
    });

    return questionPromise;
}

startPrompt().then(() => console.log('end'))

// wrong
// the second 'then' and the third 'then' method execute at the same time
'use strict';
const startPrompt = () => {

    const questionPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('first 2');resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
    questionPromise.then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('second 2');resolve();
            }, 2000);
        })
    });

    return questionPromise;
}

startPrompt().then(() => console.log('end'))
```

Comment: you must return `questionPromise.then(() => { ..` like `return questionPromise.then(() => {` because it is creates new Promise object

Comment: try return the promise with `return questionPromise.then(...);`

check the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/nuxbox/ufj8gyr1/

Comment: basically, the "second 2" code waits for questionPromise to resolve ... the `console.log('end')` also waits for questionPromise to resolve as that is what you have returned from startPrompt

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry,  I remove some code before i publish, because the origin example i wrote is a bit of long. Then above two. `then` method exec in the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really in second variant you have *two* promisses

first:

```
const questionPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('first 2');resolve();
    }, 2000);
});
```

and you return this from function,
and second:

```
questionPromise.then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('second 2');resolve();
        }, 2000);
    })
});
```

that just running inside function.

In [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) you can see that

> The then() method **returns a Promise**. It takes two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

So, this two different promisses, that just running in same time.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.